# Cannot Import Facebook SDK to Android Project

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have been trying to import Facebook SDK to my existing project. I tried the following instruction but didn't work.

- 1 : File > Import Module ..find facebook-android-sdk-4.0.1 then Finish
- 2 : Go to File > Project sturucture > dependecies tab > Module Dependencies select :Facebook
- 3 : SYNC project and Rebuild

Below is my screenshots of what I tried.

[image: File > Import Module]

[image: Select Parse SDK/facebook/build.gradle]

[image: Error about existing module name]

[image: Ended up changing the module name (not sure this is right thing to do)]

[image: Check dependency but Facebook is not there]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you are using Gradle. Why not just add the sdk as a Gradle dependency, inside your build.gradle file?

Like so:

> dependencies {
>       compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.1' }

Comment: thank you for your answer. i am new to Android Studio and everything is so confusing.  Before modifying the build.gradle file, where should locate the SDK file??

Comment: If you are using Gradle, there is no need anymore to have the SDK stored locally. Just add the dependency there and build your project. However, if you want to modify the SDK's source code, then this approach will not work for you.